# Laravel Project undefined route

Tags: html, laravel

I am tring to access the route on blade template, so I getting the error below:

```
Route \[{$name}\] not defined.
```

```php
Route::patch('/update_merchant/{merchant_id}', 'MerchantsController@update')->name('update');
```

##### Blade template

```html
<form name="merchants_data" id="merchants_data" method="post" action="{{route('update_merchant.update', [$item->merchant_id])}}">      
    {{ csrf_field() }}    
    {!! method_field('patch') !!}
```

##### Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $merchant_id)
{
    // Validation for required fields (and using some regex to validate our numeric value)
    $request->validate([
        'fees'=>'required',
    ]); 
    $merchants = Merchants_data::findorfail($merchant_id);
    // Getting values from the blade template form
    $merchants->fees = $request->get('fees');
    $merchants->save();

    return redirect('/manage_merchants')->with('success', 'Transaction Fee updated.'); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems your route name is "update" but you call "update_merchant.update"

Comment: Thank you but when I changed it to update it works, the error I getting lies with the update controller "Creating default object from empty value" and then point to this line: "Creating default object from empty value"

Comment: @NosiIshmael mark this answer as correct, and post a new question with the new error, or google the error to see what is wrong and fix it...

Answer (score 3):

As Mehran said, you named your route 'update' and you called 'update_merchant.update' in your form. When you use

```
...->name('foo');
```

That's the name you have to use in the

```
{{ route('foo') }}
```

You don't put URL in the 'route' asset, just the name.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have changed the name of the route to update...

you can do one thing is go to the root of the project in your command line.. and look up

```
php artisan route:list
```

This should give you a list of all the routes you currently have in your application ...